# CORDA Server Issue

Tags: migration, windows-server-2012, corda

We are migrating our applications to a new 2012 server and one of the applications is using `CordaNetEmbedder.dll`. I have also noticed that there is a Corda Server Installed on the current application server. I have not used this Corda Server or the net embedder from Corda earlier so I am trying to understand how this works and I want to install the latest Corda server as we are upgrading our server as well but I am finding it hard to find information on this. Is it a free software or do we have to buy this and if we have to buy it where do we buy it from and any information on installation tips and how net embedder talks to the Corda server are all a gray area for me and I could not find much help on internet too.

Appreciate if anyone here knows about this Corda server and net embedder share the information.

Comment: I have the same problem but with migration from 2003 to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old question, but there are migration guides in the documentation that you can refer to if you're ever wondering about specific versions.

here's the guide for the latest version :
https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-upgrade-notes.html